# Function in Big-O, but not in Little-O

Tags: big-o, little-o

I'm looking for a simple example function, f(n), that is Big-O of some other function, g(n), but is not Little-o of g(n). In other words, some f(n) such that f(n) is O(g(n)), but not o(g(n)).

The simplest case I can think of is f(n) = n, g(n) = n. f(n) is clearly O(g(n)). We learned in class that one definition of little-o notation is whether f(n)/g(n) as n --> infinity, goes to 0. In this case, f(n)/g(n) as n goes to infinity approaches 1, therefore f(n) is **not** o(g(n)).

Is this logic correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm so happy seeing proper usage of little-o in a coding context. Usually when I see it, it's people who mean Big-O but just can't be bothered to hold the shift key. Drives me nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct, and your conclusion is correct.

Another way of thinking about this is that `O(g)` is the set of functions which don't grow asymptotically faster than `g`, and `o(g)` is the set of functions which grow asymptotically slower than `g`. So if `f` grows at the same asymptotic rate as `g`, then `f` is in `O(g)` but not `o(g)`. The set `o(g)` is a subset of `O(g)`, and the set difference `O(g) \ o(g) = Θ(g)`.

---

As a pedant, I'm compelled to note that you asked for a *"function, f(n), that is Big-O of some **other** function, g(n)"* (emphasis mine), so you should choose a different function like `g(n) = 2n` for it to be some **other** function. ;-)